# Django - send data to view with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I want send to data to DETAILVIEW with Ajax but I have this error :

```
[HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED 5ms
```

HTML :

```
<a href="#" onclick="goto_confirm('{% url 'dmde' dmde.eater %}')" ><b> Eat </b></a>
```

JS :

```
function goto_confirm(url){
    alert(url);
    var confirmation;
    if(confirm("Are you sure ?"))
        confirmation = true;
    else
        confirmation = false;
    $.post("http://localhost:8000"+url,{"confirm": confirmation});

    return false; //pour ne pas revenir au début de la page
}
```

The url is good, I checked it in terminal and in console js.

DETAIL VIEW :

```
def dmde(request,leater):
    dmde = Announce.objects.get(eater=leater)
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        confirmation = self.request.POST.get("confirm")
        print("aaaaaaaaaa : "+confirmation)
        sup = confirmation
    return render(request,"le_site/dmde.html",locals())
```

and the url :

```
url(r'^dmde-(?P<leater>[^/]+)$', 'dmde', name="dmde"),
```

I think the process is different because the url is dynamic..

Answer (score 0):

Your DetailView does not allow POSTs.

Comment: Ah... there is nothing possibility ?

Comment: There are always possibilities, but it's really not clear what you are trying to do. What is the view supposed to do with that POST data?

Comment: It supposed to delete one article of current user. But the url of article is dynamic. A article is a model ( = detailview). I do the basic solution : a simple view.

Comment: So you need a separate Delete view, which will accept the POST and delete the item corresponding to the slug.

Comment: (The view supposed to do with that POST data is dmde.)

Comment: I change my code, but I have a new error :/ (see my second message)

Comment: I don't like this separation.. I search if I can have 2 views for one url